# Missing Moq/Nunit on subsequent builds (w/o clearing dir) in TeamCity

Tags: teamcity

From time-to-time I have a situation where I make a change in the repo, TeamCity kicks off, and then fails because it can't find Moq/NUnit. I have to build and clean the checkout dir for it to work. What could be going on?

[ResolveAssemblyReference] C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1605, 5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Moq". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.
[14:32:41]

etc.

Strange.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, as often is the case, this is my own fault. In the last step of a handful of build steps, I setup nuget packages. Unfortunately I chose "packages" as the directory, and checked "clean". On a successful build, this wipes out the packages from nuget package restore (not the ones that I made, but the ones my project depends on!).

Doh.